# Flutter - Scroll down automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, expansion

I try to do a `ExpansionPanel` who scroll automatically when I press on it. I need to scroll if I want to go to the bottom of the widget. I try with `jumpTo` and `animateTo` but not work very well.

[image: 1]

```
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), spreadRadius: 5, blurRadius: 7, offset: Offset(0, 3))]),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 25),
                      child: ExpansionPanelList(
                          expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          children: [
                            ExpansionPanel(
                                headerBuilder: (context, sOpen) {
                                  return Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                      child: TextButton(
                                          style: ButtonStyle(
                                            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[400].withOpacity(0.5)),
                                            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black87),
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              isOpen = !isOpen;
                                              expandList();
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: task('Tasks (${tasks.length})', icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, color: Colors.grey))));
                                },
                                body: Column(children: taskContains()),
                                isExpanded: isOpen,
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xfffafafa))
                          ],
                          expansionCallback: (i, iOpen) {
                            setState(() {
                              isOpen = !iOpen;
                              expandList();
                            });
                          }));

  void expandList() {
    if (isOpen) {
      controller.jumpTo(0);
      controller.animateTo((80 * tasks.length.toDouble()), duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not very well"? And please add your Code

Comment: He jumps up and down and then back up.

Comment: Whithout your code I can't check where that behavior comes from

Comment: I just edit it.

Comment: On my emulator it's work correctly but on my phone not.

Comment: Why do you use a single ExpansionPanel in a ExpansionPanelList? Do you plan on adding more panels?

Comment: For the moment I just need one. But I don't know if I use more in future.

Comment: From the documentation I found: "Once the animation has completed, the scroll position will attempt to begin a ballistic activity in case its value is not stable (for example, if it is scrolled beyond the extents and in that situation the scroll position would normally bounce back)."

So you should check if your math works out and doesn't overshoot the page size. To me 80 * x looks a bit much

Comment: Okay I check that! But the other problem is if the expansionPanel don't touch the bottom of the screen the view don't scroll too. It's open without any animation (when I remove the jumpTo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I expand, the Widget keep the old size and when I expand it, the scrollbar was at the bottom of the old widget. So we need to wait the end of the build. So I do it with that:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
              expandList();
            });
```